# Using array inside function. Change made to the array inside function is not visible to other function

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc

I am declaring an array inside **main()** and without initializing the array, I am printing the array by passing it to a function. It is printing the same value as many time as I run this program. 
 
As we know after declaring an array, it is initialized with random values. Then how it can print `1,2,3,4,5,......` for all the time.

```cpp
void print(int ar[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<ar[I]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
```

***OUTPUT :***
`0 1 2 3 4` 
When I am printing array inside ***main()*** using a for loop, then I got random values.

```cpp
int main(){
    int ar[5]={0};
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
       cout<<ar[i]<<" ";
}
```

***OUTPUT :*** `-2 6422280 1978757101 4201168 6422352`
But, when I am making change to this array inside function, then it is not reflecting change outside that function.

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void flush(int ar[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        ar[i]=0;
}
void setar(int ar[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        ar[i]=1;
}
void print(int ar[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<ar[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
int main(){
    int ar[5]={0};
    flush(ar,5);
    print(ar,5);
    setar(ar,5);
    print(ar,5);
}
```

As we know array is passed by reference, so change made inside function, should be visible outside function also. 
***SYSTEM :***
Windows 10

gcc compiler

VSCode studio

C++ 14

Comment: What is `I` in `for(int i=0;I<5;i++)`?

Comment: `cout<<i` prints the value of `i`, not the value of `ar[i]`.

Comment: Except for the typo mentioned by Eric in [works as expected](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bcd38ca007b9943).

Comment: Today i saw that some text are automatically replaced by other text on stackoverflow.com. Eg. When i type `i` it get converted into `I`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, in the print function what is it doing is that it prints the value of the integer "i", not the values of the array.
So, instead of printing "i" you should print ar[i]
`cout<<ar[i]<<" ";`